# How to run android app in debug mode on Samsung galaxy Y S5360

Tags: android, debugging

We have followed the way(android: debuggable= true in AndoirdManifest.xml and enabled usb debugging on phone) to run the android app on debug mode on the phone, but the phone is not being detected when the app is run as android application.

Here are the specifications of the phone:
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_y_s5360-4117.php

What is the issue? What is really required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to install Samsung Kies tool.

Comment: What's that? Why do i need it? Where can i get it? More details please.

Comment: this is  a software application used to communicate between the latest Samsung devices. Yuo can get it from here - http://www.samsungapps.com/about/onPc.as

Comment: I just need to run a simple app on Samsung galaxy Y S5360. Would that help me?I am using Eclipse as my IDE and thats all.

Comment: its help to me runing application from Eclipse on samsung devices.

Answer (score 1):

in case you wont be able to fix it there's another solution. I also have the same problem as yours and the same phone as yours. My phone is not detected by eclipse. But my PC can detect the phone through usb drive and through Kies(sort of like itunes for android). The altenative solution to test your program on your phone is to locate the .apk file from your projects folder in eclipse. its in the \bin folder. then copy it into your sd card. Then on your phone, locate where you placed it and click, the phone would prompt if you want to install it. install it and it should work now.(delete if you want afterwards). IF you happen to solve the issue with our phone not being detected by eclipse, pls do email me: kobe.ed6@gmail.com . Thanks and i hope i was able to help,atleast. :D

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Galaxy Y problem solved! What i did was, i plugged in the phone through USB before the first instance of eclipse on my PC. Then i hit "CTRL+F11" to run the hello world test program. And IT WORKED straight to my PHONE. I did nothing from the time i got the problem. Not even updates or anything becaus i didnt do any android development bec i was busy with something else. I just tried it just a moment ago, wishing that it work. AND IT DID WORK NOW! If the problem would still be there, try restarting your PC and plug your phone before the FIRST instance of eclipse. I dont know if the instance has to do with this problem but it is what i did and it worked! happy Android developing guys! =)