# Device is Not Recognized with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am developing android app on windows xp and have samsung nexus s  2.3.6 phone. I can run my app on emulator in Eclipse. My problem is that I can't get adb to detect the real device.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8804473/601868) will help you.

Comment: Afaik, Nexus S is an pure-google device, I don't think it requires Kies to work.

Comment: It help to me for all Samsung devices. You can also try google drivers.

Comment: Hmm, ok then. I never had a google-branded device myself, so you must know better)

Comment: Probably You didn't set "Debug Mode" on?

Comment: Thanks for this way to run the application.

Comment: But i tried another way like I send the .apk file by my email to device and install my application.But i want my device to be ran in proper way as ADB did.

Comment: try   adb install <app name>.apk     command in your cmd or terminal

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial:
http://nexusshacks.com/nexus-s-hacks/how-to-install-nexus-s-windows-usb-drivers/

**Upd**

Also, try google's own usb driver. It's available through Android SDK Manager.

And after performing all this driver-related stuff, if the problem is still there - don't forget to restart your PC, sometimes it's the last thing that's missing.