# Android Gingerbread phones are not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, windows-8.1, usbserial

I can connect and use Android 3.0+ , 4.0+ devices without any problem and can see and use them from Eclipse as well.

But, when I try to connect any Froyo/Gingerbread device to my pc, it is not even recognized that any usb device is connected to it.

I did some research and tried installing driver from own website, installed kies, turned on and off usb debugging, tried connecting as storage,etc but no, nothing is working. It is just being charged when devices are connected. Pc doesn't see any device is connected to it.

My OS is Windows 8.1 - 64bit.

While trying, I've followed these links:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2327476

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-y/602088-usb-wont-connect-samsung-galaxy-y.html

[How to run android app in debug mode on Samsung galaxy Y S5360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804430/how-to-run-android-app-in-debug-mode-on-samsung-galaxy-y-s5360)

Any help and suggestion for a solution are most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a temporary fix for now. Thanks to dznk on this topic, I've managed to fix my problem.

http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/251273-windows-8-1-n-wont-recognize-my-device.html

If I change USB slot a few times, the PC manages to see the device but every time I disconnect the device, I need to connect to the other slot (USB 2.0 to 3.0 or vice-versa) for it to recognize the device again. Until another solution comes, this one is the best that I've achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a Win8.1 PC, Eclipse 4.3.2 and the ADT 23.0.2. For Android 2.3.4 when you plug in the USB cable (assuming you have already set the phone USB connection to PC Mode), Windows should start Installing a new device driver. It can take all of the "several minutes" they warn, so you could have not noticed it was happening and you inadvertently canceled it.

You can check the Win Device Manager. My Gingerbread test phone is a Motorola DroidX. When it is connected to a USB port, the first device in the DM listing is "ADB Interface". Under that there is a "Mot Composite ADB Interface". Under Portable Devices there is an "MTP USB Device".
Both those disappear from the DM when you unplug the USB cable and re-appear when you plug it into the same or a different port.